# NavigationService.Navigate throws an exception and invokes Application_UnhandledException in WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, navigationservice

I am developing a simple WP8 application using VS 2013. I have a MainPage.xaml and added a new page called Page1.xaml. I have a list of options on screen when a user clicks on "new item" I want to open a new page to add new item (Page1.xaml for instance).
On the list selection changed event I have written the following code:

```
    private void OptionssList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selection = (MenuItem) e.AddedItems[0];
        switch (selection.Id)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I try to debug the application, I notice that the constructor of Page1.xaml is invoked if I had an OnNavigatedTo event handler it is also been invoked however after all this an Unhandled exception is thrown. There is no code that I can see when the exception is thrown however it invokes the Application_UnhandledException event handler.

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

The exception details is as shown below:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I would like to know if I am missing something. I referred to the sample it also shows similar way to Navigate, did not notice any things fancy.

Comment: Maybe we're going to need a little bit more details to understand what happens. There's probably a problem into your Page1.xaml, does it contain something special?

Comment: There is nothing special on my page one.. I have just created a new page I have not added any control to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

i know this may be a very stupid question, your code looks fine to me, is your page not maybe in another folder? I always put my pages in a folder called UI, so my code will look something like this:

```
                                         /folder1/folder2/pagename
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/UI/Generics/Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Just make sure of that, cause that usually get me.

Comment: Both my pages are in the root folder.